# How to evaluate a complex limit

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I have to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow-i}\frac{z^4}{z^3+1}$$

I found that just trying to plug in the point I get:

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow-i}\frac{z^4}{z^3+1} = \frac{(-i)^4}{(-i)^3+1} = \frac{1}{i+i} = \frac{1}{2i}.$$

Is this right? It feels like it shouldn't be this simple.

Comment: It's that simple, but you made a mistake anyway.

Comment: @M.Turner
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow-i}\frac{z^4}{z^3 + i}=\lim_{z\rightarrow-i}\frac{(-1)(-1)}{i + i}=\frac{1}{2i}=\frac{i}{-2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight the previous points made:

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow-i}\frac{z^4}{z^3+1} = \frac{(-i)^4}{(-i)^3+1} = \frac{1}{i+1} =\frac{1}{i+1}(\frac{-i+1}{-i+1})= \frac{-i+1}{2}=\frac{-1}{2}i+\frac{1}{2}$$

You just needed to multiply by the conjugate and to give you the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: OH DAMN! Wait the question is wrong. It actually was:

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow-i}\frac{z^4}{z^3 + i}$$

Comment: It happens to the best of us.

Comment: so is $\frac{1}{2i}$ the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your $+1$ in the denominator became a $+i$.  Fix that to get the correct answer of $\dfrac12 - \dfrac12i$.  But otherwise, yes, it's that simple.  But it won't always be that simple.

Comment: Oh my gosh! Such a silly mistake. But I also have this other problem too.

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(z-2i)(7z-3)}{(1-iz)^2(1+5z)}$$

I've tried to expand it but it just looks worse:

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}\frac{7z^2-3z-14zi+6i}{(1-2zi-z^2)(1+5z)}$$

Is this the right way to approach this?

Comment: @John, that "other method" you're using is not correct.  You've added an extra factor of $1+5z$ when moving it to the numerator.  Fixing this is not enough since the method is invalid in general.  This is because direct substitution will give you $\dfrac{c \cdot \infty}{\infty}$, where $c$ is some constant that depends on where you put the single factor of $1+5z$.  But this expression is indeterminate.

Comment: Valid point. That was my mistake.